# Solana inflation mechanism design

Tags: token, staking, economics

When Solana quotes a percentage inflation figure, is that to be understood as annual inflation of the current circulating supply?

For example, if inflation is 10% and current circulating supply is 400 million, then in one year 40 million additional tokens are expected to exist. Are these additional 40 million tokens distributed amongst Stakers proportionally?

I.e. in a hypothetical scenario, if there were two stakers each staking 100 SOL, would they each receive 20 million tokens throughout the year?

Answer (score 2):

Good question! The answer is yes - inflation rate is relative to the current supply.

This is why individual staking rates go up when the percentage of SOL staked goes down, and why rates go down when the percentage of SOL staked goes up. So in your example, if there were only 200 SOL staked, the staking rate would be huge (like OlympusDAO-level yields).

You can see the current staking rate by invoking `solana -um inflation` from the command line. You can also see more of an explanation [here](https://docs.solana.com/inflation/inflation_schedule).

Comment: Thank you very much! Great to see my assumptions being confirmed :)